# Firebase receives data from real device but doesn't from an emulator....why?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-emulator

I have used Firebase for 2 years, and suddenly it stopped receiving any data from the emulator, but at the same time, it receives from an actual device !!!

My Code:

```
val database =Firebase.database
val myRef = database.getReference("message")
uploadButton.setOnClickListener { 
  myRef.setValue("Hello, World!") 
}
```

What I have tried

- Used multiple different emulators (those with google play) with different SDK
- Changed `SHA1` and `google-services.json`
- In Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> SDK Tools downloaded and activated Google play service
- Reinstalled Android Studio
- Installed Windows 10 again
- Updated Google Play services version
- Tried different projects on different firebase accounts
- Activated Sign-in methods in the firebase console
- Upgraded billing plan in firebase
- Disabled the firewall
- Disabled the anti-virus
- I opened all the ports
- Searched the web for several days and did many other things I can't even remember now

Comment: "it stopped receiving any data" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What is the code that behaves that way? Do you have any errors?

Comment: I used a very basic code to test the firebase real-time database, and I tried all the solutions I get from the internet,

Comment: and this is a same question link :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73370728/firebase-doesnt-work-on-android-studio-emulator

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: it is a very basic code and it doesn't work
//////////////////////////////////////
val database =Firebase.database
 val myRef = database.getReference("message")
 uploadButton.setOnClickListener {
            myRef.setValue("Hello, World!")
        }
////////////////////////////////

Comment: I have seen a very similar problem this week: A project nicely working inside the Android emulator now fails receiving data from a firebase realtime database, just after I upgraded the emulator to version 31.3.10 (as suggested by Android Studio). I could repeat the same problem on an independent system (both: Windows 10, up to date Android studio version, project upgraded to newest SDK). Also there after upgrading the emulator, access to the database fails. Unfortunately I do not remember the version number of the emulator that still worked. I just know it is was about 4 month older.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was solved when I downgraded the emulator version, and this is the answer that helped me :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73395525/17225971