# Android Emulator your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, emulation

I am trying to Flutter Run on the android emulator but I take a error. However Android emulator has a internet connection.

Error:

```
W/Firestore(12362): This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.**

W/Firestore(12643): (24.2.2) [WatchStream]: (942dfc6) Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Channel shutdownNow invoked, cause=null}.
W/DynamiteModule(12643): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
I/DynamiteModule(12643): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
W/ProviderInstaller(12643): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
```

how can I fix this?

Comment: have you found any solution for this?

Comment: Are you sure that your Host OS has a "healthy internet connection" ?

Comment: yep I am sure my host has a healthy internet connection

Comment: @JaysonTamayo yep I did download 31.2.10 and its fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and downgrading Android Emulator (31.3.10 —> 30.9.5) solved my problem.

[Firebase doesn't work on Android Studio Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73370728/firebase-doesnt-work-on-android-studio-emulator)